In BotFrameworkAdapter, how to use Managed Identity instead of MicrosoftAppCredentials
We are using BotFrameworkAdapter in our project to send notifications to users.
The method CreateConversationAsync, uses MicrosoftAppCredentials to authenticate.
We want to move away from secrets on App registration. So using MicrosoftAppCredentials will not be feasible, since it requires microsoft app id and microsoft app password.
Is there a way to use managed identity here ?

I don't think so, the authorization process is a significant aspect of the bot framework and it occurs on different tenant and it called as mult-tenant bot framework authorization token. I don't think without app cred you can't authorize the bot framework.

Accepting / upvoting an answer serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" and upvote it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Your primary issue is your use of the BotFrameworkAdapter which does not support UserAssignedMSI (User-assigned managed identity). Additionally, this adapter class is now deprecated.
Since I don't know which SDK language you are using, I will explain things using JS. The implementation is basically the same between SDKs.
Also, since I don't know which SDK version you are using, at a minimum if your version supports switching, you should switch your code to use the CloudAdapter. If your version doesn't support CloudAdapter, then you should update to one that does. You can reference the samples located in the BotBuilder-Samples repo regarding setup.
To quickly demonstrate setting up the CloudAdapter adapter, you will need to:
Create the credentials factory
const credentialsFactory = new ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory({
  MicrosoftAppId: <<Your MicrosoftAppId>>,
  // MicrosoftAppPassword: '', // Not used for managed identity
  MicrosoftAppType: <<Your MicrosoftAppType>>, // Should be 'UserAssignedMSI'
  MicrosoftAppTenantId: <<Your MicrosoftAppTenantId>>
});

Create the authentication configuration
const botFrameworkAuthentication = createBotFrameworkAuthenticationFromConfiguration(
  null,
  credentialsFactory
);

Create the adapter
const adapter = new CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication)

As you can see from the docs, the signature for the createConversationAsync() method is essentially the same. You really shouldn't experience any headaches here.

At this point, follows the steps listed in the Add authentication to a bot to setup the Azure resource(s) necessary for using UserAssignedMSI. Keep in mind that:

The Azure Bot resource (registration) app type must be set to 'User-Assigned Managed Identity'. This can only be done at the time of registration. If your bot's current app registration isn't set to this, you will need to create a new resource. There is no method or process for changing the app type.

If you are using the Python SDK, it now supports using UserAssignedMSI due to a recent update. Any docs stating otherwise have not been updated (at the time of this posting).

The Java SDK is deprecated and does not support UserAssignedMSI. Due to its deprecation, there are no plans to update it.


Hope of help!

I'm trying to implement this (for Teams), but running into a few blockers and struggling to find docs on it.
(1) for SSO scenario, you'll STILL need an Entra ID app (aka: AAD app) and configure the AzBot's registration's oauth connection settings with it to handle permissions, correct?
(2) Dev & test... when working locally, how is your local codebase supposed to auth with the bot if it's using the UserAssignedMSI that only exists in Azure? Seems you're forced to deploy just to test, or an I missing something?
